# How to create a CSS Animation that is responding to horizontal mouse movement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I need to apply a CSS animation when a user moves his mouse horizontally.

This is a picture that tries describe what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I would be glad to use JQuery or JavaScript as a solution.

Comment: You can use the CSS pseudo selector :onhover to show or hide html based off when the mouse is hovered over an element.

Comment: yes, but I can do this only with the horizontal movement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JQuery's `mousemove` method](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/). Then listen for `down` event.

You can then apply in that callback some css transformation, also with [JQuery's Animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Ok thanks, I fixed it.